# Disable stop word filtering in a MongoDB text search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am wondering if it would be possible to disable only the stop word filtering in the MongoDB text search. Sometimes I just want to search for words like "you", "I", "was", etc. I would still like to take advantage of the **stemming**. **Just not the stop word filtering**.

`db.collection.find({$text: {$search: "you"}})`

The above would not return any results.

But a traditional approach like

`db.collection.find({shortDescription: new RegExp(".*you.*",'i')})` would give me what I want.

So, how can I have the text search but also be able to search these words (stop words).

Answer (score 6):

You can disable stop words by changing the language value of your text index when you create it. From the MongoDB documentation:

> If you specify a language value of "none", then the text search uses simple tokenization with no list of stop words and no stemming [[source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages)].

So create your index using:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   { content : "text" },
   { default_language: "none" }
)
```

[[code source]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/specify-language-for-text-index/)

Comment: You can check out the list of English stop words here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/0e3b3ca8480ddddf5d0105d11a94bd4698335312/src/mongo/db/fts/stop_words_english.txt

Comment: Like I mentioned, I would like to take advantage of **stemming** but without filtering stop words. The solution you are suggesting takes away stemming.

Answer (score 0):

when you are inserting any text for `text-indexed` field. The index values are created after filtering the text. 
So when you are searching for any stop words it's not present in the index value list. That's the reason its never going to search out the stop words. It's by design and probably non-editable.You have to use `Regex` for such criteria. I hope there is no other way available.

Comment: Thought so. But is there a way, to find out whether a particular word is a stop word or not, then I could trigger a regex search instead of a text search?

Comment: you can easily get the list of stop words from google and maintain a array to lookup. If the incoming word is in the list use `Regex` search or else `$text` search

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the stemming, I assume there will never be *just* stop words, but always at least one "normal" word too. On top of that, I hope you know exactly *which* stop words you want.

If that's the case, I suggest to **put the stop words into quotes**. [As the docs say](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases), if there are phrases present "the search performs a logical `AND` of the phrase with the individual terms in the search string." And thankfully, it appears that stop words are not stripped from phrases.

**For example,** assume a collection with the following documents:

```
{"text": "I love blueberries"},
{"text": "She loves blueberries"},
{"text": "She loved the last blueberry most."}
```

Searching for `blueberry`, `blueberry I` or `blueberries she` each time returns all three collections. But searching for `blueberries "she"` only returns the last two collections, i.e. stemming is considered and the existence of the stop word enforced.

---

Sadly, **this won't work if you're searching for *just* stop words**, i.e. searching for `"she"` will return nothing. Also, **you can't `OR` several stop words**: If you add "and me" to each of the first two documents so that they become "I love blueberries and me" and "She loves blueberries and me" respectively, searching for `blueberry "she" "me"` will only return the second document.

However, **beware of extremely short stop words** that may be part of other words: On my test database, searching for `blueberry "I"` returned *both* the first and second documents -- I assume due to the `i` in "blueberr`i`es".